# how can I make a hole in a collision or control opaque_to_polygons() on gdscript 4

Tags: gdscript, godot4

Newbee in godot and coding. trying to make destructable enviroment like in worms games. I want to place a collision on the png map. have a code that work but it ignores empty spaces enclosed within non-empty ones. help.

```
extends StaticBody2D

var levelBM = BitMap.new()
var arr
var poly = Polygon2D.new()
var polygons = []
var collision_polygons = []

func _ready():
    levelBM.create_from_image_alpha($Sprite.texture.get_image(),0.1)
    var offsetX = 0
    var offsetY = 0
    if ($Sprite.texture.get_width() % 2 != 0):
        offsetX = 1
    if ($Sprite.texture.get_height() % 2 != 0):
        offsetY = 1
    update_bitmap(offsetX, offsetY)
    $Sprite.visible = false
    update_bitmap(offsetX, offsetY)

func update_bitmap(offsetX, offsetY):
    arr = levelBM.opaque_to_polygons(Rect2(-$Sprite.texture.get_image().get_width()/2, -$Sprite.texture.get_image().get_height()/2, $Sprite.texture.get_image().get_width()*2,$Sprite.texture.get_image().get_height()*2))
    
    for i in polygons:
        i.queue_free()
    for i in collision_polygons:
        i.queue_free()
    poly = Polygon2D.new()
    poly.set_polygons(arr)
    queue_redraw()
    polygons = []
    collision_polygons = []
    for i in arr.size():
        polygons.append(Polygon2D.new())
        collision_polygons.append(CollisionPolygon2D.new())
        polygons[i].polygon = arr[i]
        polygons[i].texture = $Sprite.texture
        polygons[i].position -= Vector2(($Sprite.texture.get_width() / 2) + offsetX, ($Sprite.texture.get_height() / 2) + offsetY) * scale.x
        collision_polygons[i].polygon = arr[i]
        collision_polygons[i].position -= Vector2(($Sprite.texture.get_width() / 2) + offsetX, ($Sprite.texture.get_height() / 2) + offsetY) * scale.x
        call_deferred("add_child",polygons[i])
        call_deferred("add_child",collision_polygons[i])
```

Comment: might be better to ask in a gamedev forum

Comment: See: [SUPER EASY 2D DESTRUCTIBLE TERRAIN in Godot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiKsyOLacwA&forced)